I am trying to create a Moneris checkout integration with JavaScript on my site. The JSON call is not returning an expected ticket number
I am looking to code a page to replace the an out Hosted Payment Page on Moneris (see https://github.com/Moneris/Moneris-Checkout).  I need to set the page to post some items etc. and have the user perform the transaction and then I need to read the results back.  Can someone share an example of this?
I have tried to follow integration guide but I seem to be missing something:
Relevant code (head):
<script src="https://gatewayt.moneris.com/chktv2/js/chkt_v2.00.js"></script> 

Relevant code (body):
<div id="outerDiv" style="width:650px; height:600px; border: solid 1px black;">
    <div id="monerisCheckout">
    {
        "store_id": "XXX",
        "api_token": "XXXXX",
        "checkout_id": "XXXX",
        "environment": "qa",
        "action": "preload",
        "txn_total":"3.00",
        "order_no": "1234",
        "language": "en",
        "cart":{
        "items":[
           {                                      
                "description":"One item",
                "product_code":"one_item",
                "unit_cost":"1.00",
                "quantity":"1"
           },
           {
                "description":"Two item",
                "product_code":"two_item",
                "unit_cost":"1.00",
                "quantity":"1"
           },
           {
                "description":"Three item",
                "product_code":"three_item",
                "unit_cost":"1.00",
                "quantity":"1"
           }
           ],
        },

        "contact_details":{
            "first_name":"bill",
            "last_name":"smith",
            "email":"test@moneris.com",
            "phone":"4165551234"
        },
    }
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var myCheckout = new monerisCheckout();
    myCheckout.setMode("qa");
    myCheckout.setCheckoutDiv("monerisCheckout");
    var myCheckout = new monerisCheckout();
    myCheckout.setCallback("page_loaded", myPageLoad);    
    myCheckout.startCheckout("");

    function myPageLoad(ex){
        console.log(ex);
    }

function myPaymentReceipt(ex){}
</script>


you seem to be missing some code in the head for a proper response

I have a myPageLoad to log the response.  Is something else missing?
